# export shell function to su as a user with ksh default shell

Tags: function, export, ksh, su

I have a situation where only root can mailx, and only ops can restart the process.  I want to make an automated script that both restarts the process and sends an email about doing so.

When I try this using a function the function is "not found".

I had something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function restartprocess {
/usr/bin/processcontrol.sh start
}

export -f restartprocess

su - ops -c "restartprocess"

mailx -s "process restarted" myemail.mydomain.com < emailmessage.txt

exit 0
```

It told me that the function was not found.  After some troubleshooting, it turned out that the ops user's default shell is ksh.

I tried changing the script to run in ksh, and changing "export -f" to "typeset -xf", and still the function was not found. Like:
ksh: exportfunction not found

I finally gave up and just called the script (that was in the function directly) and that worked. It was like:

```
su - ops -c "/usr/bin/processcontrol.sh start"
```

(This is all of course a simplification of the real script).

Given that user ops has default shell is ksh and I can't change that or modify sudoers, is there a way to export a function such that I can su as ops (and I need to run ops's profile) and execute that function?

I made sure ops user had permission to the directory of the script I wanted it to execute, and permission to run that script.

Any education about this would be appreciated!

Comment: Can I assume that is `export -f restart` (and not `export -f restartprocess`) is a typo in your posting, and not in your actual code? If so, please correct in your question above. It may also help to include exact text of the 'function not found' message. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are many restrictions for exporting functions, especially
combined with `su - ...` with different accounts and different shells.

Instead, turn your script inside out and put *all* of the command
that is to be run inside a function in the calling shell.

Something like: (Both bash and ksh)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

function restartprocess {
    /bin/su - ops -c "/usr/bin/processcontrol.sh start"
}

if restartprocess; then
    mailx -s "process restarted" \
        myemail@mydomain.com < emailmessage.txt
fi

exit 0
```

This will hide all of the `/bin/su` processing inside the `restartprocess` function, and can be expanded at will.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I would vote up but apparently I am not yet allowed to do that.

Comment: You should still be able to accept the answer (as you asked it), or if not, provide feedback on how it could be improved.  Also, try to spend time on some of the other stackexchange sites, and complete your profile.